# missing dependencies for qtdeclarative-dev:i386 on Ubuntu 64 bit 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit, qt

I want to install the 32 bit qt libraries on ubuntu 64 bit, but apt-get can not resolve the dependencies.

first I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then I rebooted and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative-dev:i386
```

and I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qtdeclarative5-dev:i386 : Depends: libqt5quick5:i386 (= 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                    libqt5quick5-gles:i386 but it is not installable
                           Depends: libqt5quickparticles5:i386 (= 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                    libqt5quickparticles5-gles:i386 but it is not installable
                           Depends: libqt5quicktest5:i386 (= 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: qtbase5-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This worked on Ubuntu 64 bit 14.04.2, but now it seems Qt has not kept up with the HWE stack change?

Anyone else having this issue and have any ideas how to solve it?

EDIT:

more information:

**dpkg --print-foreign-architectures; uname -a; lsb_release -a**

```
daniel@daniel-Ubuntu:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures; uname -a; lsb_release -a
i386
Linux daniel-Ubuntu 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**sudo apt-get install libqt5quick5 libqt5quick5:i386**

```
daniel@daniel-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libqt5quick5 libqt5quick5:i386
[sudo] password for daniel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5quick5 is already the newest version.
libqt5quick5 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5quick5:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 or
                              libgl1:i386
                     Depends: libqt5gui5:i386 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5:i386**

```
daniel@daniel-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5gui5:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 or
                            libgl1:i386
                   Depends: libgles2-mesa:i386 (>= 7.8.1) or
                            libgles2:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT2:

**sudo apt-cache policy libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386; sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa:i386**

```
daniel@daniel-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386; sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
[sudo] password for daniel: 
libgles2-mesa:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
  Version table:
     10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libgles2-mesa:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
  Version table:
     10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
  Version table:
     10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
  Version table:
     10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
                        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
 libgles2-mesa:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures; uname -a; lsb_release -a`

Comment: It could be a long way, have you enough time? `sudo apt-get install libqt5quick5 libqt5quick5:i386` and add also this output to your question.

Comment: Next step: `sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5:i386`

Comment: Next: `apt-cache policy libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386; sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by manually installing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, then installing qtdeclarative5-dev:i386. I am not sure why apt-get could not resolve this dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev:i386
```